# In this current therapy circuit design how to reduce output current

Tags: capacitor, ac, transformer, power-engineering

Here, I plan to switching two N-type MOSFET by using 12 V step up center tap transformer (1:10). My output is around 120 Vac. Its great but the current is nearly 17.5 A. How can I reduce the current in the output side? I plan to get not more than 20 mA and stable current too. I already use so many stuff still no get success. Give me some idea for reduce output side current. Also give me some suggestion if my circuit design is not proper..
Also suggest me some capacitor and inductors parts with proper value..

[image: My circuit design]

Comment: "current is nearly 17.5 A" where? What are you actually trying to achieve with 20ma at 120VAC?

Comment: It looks like you are shorting your output with your ammeter.

Comment: Your amp meter is shorting the output. The amount of current drawn in the output depends on the load you put on your system. Try placing your amp meter between your transformer and the voltmeter

Comment: @pjc50 actually I plan to made, current  therapy device.. Which is easy to travel, and small size device..

Comment: By circuit therapy do you mean you plan to shock people with this? Please dont...

Comment: That's. Why, I plan to current not more than 20 mA

Comment: Adding 6600uF wont help with that.. can't you add a high value series resistor?

Comment: Please define the open circuit voltage you want and is it ac or dc. If ac then what frequency? Supply details of the transformer too. Next, what is the power output under full load conditions and what is the impedance of that load. What should be the short circuit output current?

Comment: In my case, input is 12 V analog dc. But final output is 120 V ac with 50 Hz frequency. Now short circuit output is 17.5 A

Comment: Current [therapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parrilla_%28torture%29) at 17.5 A seems a bit too intensive to me.

Answer (score 5):

You are using 2x 2200 uF capacitors across an AC output of supposedly 120 V. What are you thinking of? This is a disastrous idea. I'm not surprised at all about the current you are taking. You can't put such big electrolytic capacitors across an AC output and hope that you will get a nice sinewave. You need to filter the output with an inductor and non-polarized capacitors.

Also, driving the MOSFETs (IRFZ44N) from an Arduino output is asking for problems too. Try using a proper MOSFET driver.

I'm assuming the ammeter is a mistake because connecting as you have is just shorting the output out.

Comment: This should be as a comment since it's not answering the question

Comment: @MarceloEspinozaVargas don't be so hasty. I was adding to the answer.

Comment: @Andy aka here, Arduino is just for generate PWM for MOSFET, in my case I use switching both MOSFET..

Comment: @Andy aka, Okk.. Let me try with inductor and non-polarized capacitors..  Okk I will put ammeter in proper way..

Comment: Still I am waiting for suitable answer, because this device will use for human body, and current should not be higher than 20mA..

Comment: See my comment to your question.

Answer (score 3):

The ammeter is shorted directly across the power supply.  Always connect ammeters in *series* with a load.  Voltmeters go across.

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/experiments/chpt-2/ammeter-usage/

> The most common way to measure current in a circuit is to break the circuit open and insert an “ammeter” in series (in-line) with the circuit so that all electrons flowing through the circuit also have to go through the meter. Because measuring current in this manner requires the meter be made part of the circuit, it is a more difficult type of measurement to make than either voltage or resistance.

Essentially, you're short-circuiting the power supply and measuring the short-circuit current that the PSU is capable of.

This **NOT** what you're supposed to do with an ammeter.

[image]